# ApolloGraphQL: Non web socket subscriptions?

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, nestjs, apollo-server

We have an app that implements essentially this guide exactly:

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/subscriptions/

It's been great. We've had great success and the app has been doing great.

What we have started running into though, is that various large corporations block their internal staff's web sockets.  They return a 403 when we try to upgrade to the web sockets.

I've been googling around and just don't see much for anything in the Apollo community for non web socket subscriptions.  Everything guide/article/example is based on web sockets.

Ideally i'd use something like socket.io, that falls back to long polling is a solution I was thinking.  But everyone only uses the subscriptions-transport-ws library (we use it).  I found a dated lib called subscriptions-transport-sse, but hesitant to try it and my server setup would need a lot of refactoring. We use nestjs and the Apollo GraphQL module.

Has anyone else solved how to fallback to a different transport?  I'm really trying to avoid writing my own, but looks like the choices are that or switch to another framework that has it built in?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe your app could fall back to query polling instead of subscriptions? It is really easy to set up polling for queries in apollo client and would not require any changes on the server except that the load might go up.

Comment: Thanks @Herku. I could certainly do this, would require some refactoring but seems like my best bet.  Two things I don't love about it though. My root object graph is quite large, and I only query it once, then have subscriptions sync the children nodes. My app typically has between 5-20 other clients making updates all at the same time so I would have to keep the polling interval very small to make sure UX doesn't suffer.  Really appreciate your input!!

Comment: Have you tried using wss?
Maybe these answers are useful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28828153/2805067
https://superuser.com/a/1263106

Comment: Maybe create extra entry points into the graph so that you can query similar things like your subscription. Also, writing your own apollo link might not be such a big deal if you build on socket.io.